# cannot install docker on windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, config.json

I am pretty new to docker with windows.  I had not problem with it on my personal mac.  However, I have been unable to get docker to run correctly on windows 10.

I have followed along the accepted stack overflow answer [Cannot start docker after installation on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885985/cannot-start-docker-after-installation-on-windows).

However, when I run

```
docker-machine ls
```

I get

```
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default            not found    Error                             open C:\Users\Steve\.docker\machine\machines\default\config.json: The system cannot find the file specified.
test      -        virtualbox   Stopped                 Unknown
```

I can see that the **DRIVER** is not found and that **config.json** cannot be found.

I tried uninstalling docker toolbox but that did not make a difference. There seems to be multiple additional issues when I check **docker-machine**.  Not sure though how to get past this.

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40052629/docker-not-working-in-windows10?

Answer (score 0):

- first,you should **reboot** your win10 computer (to make your env
  variable valid.
- second,run  `docker-machine rm -f default`  in your computer
  commandline.
- last,double click **Docker Quickstart Terminal** and waiting to auto
  complete.and it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps if you are trying like me with windows:

1. Open Windows defender
   [image]
2. Disable Ransomeware protection
   [image]

**3. Install Docker**

4. optional back Ransomeware protection