# error installing docker via powershell

Tags: powershell

Got this error while installing docker on windows server 2016. any idea?

> PS C:\Users\Administrator> Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName
>   DockerMsftProvider Install-Package : Cannot rename because item at
>   'C:\Program Files\dummyName' does not exist. At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package],
>   Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage

Answer (score 3):

reply here worked for me...

[Cannot Install Docker on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351564/cannot-install-docker-on-windows-10)

- Open Windows defender
- Disable Ransomware protection
- Install Docker
- **optional** Enable Ransomware protection

Answer (score 2):

I found this issue on:  https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22009935
The problem seems to be caused by Symantec Antivirus. To stop it press Win Key + R key and then type in smc -stop or smc start (depending on what you want to do). I did this and the error did not appear anymore.

Comment: Thanks, in my case it was Avira.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the docker folder to become Docker

```
    $dummyName = 'dummyName'
    $null = Rename-Item -Path $script:pathDockerRoot -NewName $env:ProgramFiles\$dummyName
    while (!(Test-Path $env:ProgramFiles\$dummyName)) 
    { 
        Start-Sleep 1
        $null = Rename-Item -Path $script:pathDockerRoot -NewName $env:ProgramFiles\$dummyName -ErrorAction Continue -Verbose
    }

    $null = Rename-Item -Path $env:ProgramFiles\$dummyName -NewName $script:pathDockerRoot
```