# Docker build command creates large amount of folders in windowsfilter folder: what's the purpose and how to control

Tags: windows, docker, containers, windows-server-2019

I'm building a new image like so `docker build . -t test` and copy contents from host OS folder into it:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN mkdir root
RUN cd root
WORKDIR /root
RUN mkdir test
COPY test /root/test
    #USING 'COPY' here instead of 'ADD' because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958140/what-is-the-difference-between-the-copy-and-add-commands-in-a-dockerfile
```

I get this output in Powershell:

```
PS D:\Programs> docker build . -t test
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.644GB
Step 1/7 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
ltsc2019: Pulling from windows/servercore
4612f6d0b889: Pull complete
c67ded6868b6: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:1be9c8378b8c32d31538253a4b96169f5138a5f6d4c0a04e8d8f9a80b9ac8097
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
 ---> d1724c2d9a84
Step 2/7 : SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
 ---> Running in 1bfefefbe433
Removing intermediate container 1bfefefbe433
 ---> 37de702deb33
Step 3/7 : RUN mkdir root
 ---> Running in e26d6b49ced7


    Directory: C:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         9/8/2021   1:07 PM                root


Removing intermediate container e26d6b49ced7
 ---> 451c4d3f3ea1
Step 4/7 : RUN cd root
 ---> Running in 74a228f8118f
Removing intermediate container 74a228f8118f
 ---> 3f175ac67f1d
Step 5/7 : WORKDIR /root
 ---> Running in 5f783d5b2332
Removing intermediate container 5f783d5b2332
 ---> 68b24e033f87
Step 6/7 : RUN mkdir test
 ---> Running in 5771bb7a593a


    Directory: C:\root


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         9/8/2021   1:08 PM                test


Removing intermediate container 5771bb7a593a
 ---> 35fa0b2af157
Step 7/7 : COPY test /root/test
 ---> 60eab8242865
Successfully built 60eab8242865
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

It creates EIGHT(!) folders on the host OS in folder "\docker\windowsfilter"

This seems excessive, it looks like a folder for each step in my `Dockerfile`, so what are all these folders for and could I prevent creation/autodelete the unneeded ones to keep everything tidy?

Host OS: Windows Server 2019 standard Version 1809 17763.2114
Docker: version 20.10.4, build 110e091

Please note that I do NOT use the Docker Desktop application, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67009080/install-docker-windows-server-2019-the-term-docker-is-not-recognized-as-the-n) how I installed Docker.

**Update 1**

I updated my Dockerfile based on @Noam's suggestion like so:

```
#RUN mkdir root
#RUN cd root
#WORKDIR /root
WORKDIR /root #creates root directory if not exists, then enters it
```

After this change, 6 folders (instead of 8) are created in `windowsfilter`, so my hunch that Docker creates a folder for each command in Dockerfile seems to be correct.

Comment: What windows version do you have? please specify the exact version (i.e. home, pro, server, general version, version build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hallo @Flo this issue seems to be a long time issue specifically with docker desktop,

### Causes:

One option that some times seems to explain it is upgrading from older versions of docker desktop and the software not cleaning up old directories.

Another I that docker saves built image layers there so if you have many versions of the same image your dangling ones could reside there requesting a run of `docker image prune` or maybe even `docker system prune`

### Solutions:

An opensource cleanup script has been published and it seems to help a great deal, its called [docker-ci-zap](https://github.com/moby/docker-ci-zap) and for the most part it appears to handle it quite well.

if the issue still persists there is a fix suggested in the [docker for desktop github issue page](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/745#issuecomment-319930974) is adding **-removing** suffix to the folder names in the `windowsfilter` directory followed by a restart to allow docker to cleanup the unneeded folders

if it's still causing issues try returning to [factory deafults](https://www.kindacode.com/article/how-to-reset-docker-desktop/) and if that doesn't do it either maybe a fresh [docker for desktop install](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop) might seal the deal though even then some experienced some difficulties so eventually if it really bothers and you need to use it, reinstalling windows usually looks like the final blow.

### suggestion for Dockerfile improvments

in your Dockerfile the lines describing the folders might cause problems up a head du to unabsolute paths and improper use of the Dockerfile command.

replace:

```
RUN mkdir root
RUN cd root
WORKDIR /root
```

with:

```
WORKDIR /root
```

it achives the same purpose (creating and entering the new (if didn't exist yet) directory)

### what does docker-ci-zap do?

You can get a rough sense by looking at [the code](https://github.com/moby/docker-ci-zap/blob/master/zap.go) used to compile the exe file that resides in the GitHub repo:

it uses the [`hcsshim`](https://github.com/microsoft/hcsshim) driver and its [`DestroyLayer`](https://github.com/microsoft/hcsshim/blob/master/internal/wclayer/destroylayer.go) function that deletes the layer files from the host disk, or as the docs put it:

> DestroyLayer will remove the on-disk files representing the layer
> with the given path, including that layer's containing folder, if
> any.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my update 1. Not sure if relevant but I do NOT use the Docker Desktop application

Comment: @Flo just saw how you did it, you might benefit from using docker desktop instead since it has more community and commercial support and it works on windows server 2019. also, what you saw regarding the folders might confirm the image layers hypothesis

Comment: Thanks again. I explicitly choose NOT to go with Docker Desktop because I run a VPS that does not support Hyper-V, which is required for Docker Desktop.
Knowing that I don't run Docker Desktop today, does the bug you mention still apply?
And is there perhaps a way to consolidate commands further in my Dockerfile?
(ps I checked `docker-ci-zap.exe` but it's unclear to me what it does exactly)

Comment: @Flo ok I understand regarding the issue with Hyper-V. people usually run it (docker-ci-zap) when folders under `windowsfilter` take a few dozens of GB of storage (i.e. 40GB worth), if its kept the same size then it's just the matter of things and the implementation of docker as you're using it, it's just how it saves those layers of the built images. If you have experience with Linux I'd suggest going that route but not if its too much and you're generally satisfied with the way things already are

Comment: Thanks. Then my last question would be what exactly does docker-ci-zap do under the hood? I can't find a description on Github. Does it `prune` ? Delete everything? Delete old folders? Large folders? Something else?

Comment: Thanks, will award the bounty when allowed by SO (in 37mins). ps. you don't need to [at] mention users in comments, they always get auto-notified :)
In the meantime: since you seem to know your Docker stuff, could you perhaps have a look at this other post of mine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69103701/copy-contents-from-host-os-into-docker-image-without-rebuilding-image

Comment: added an answer I think will help you