# Enabling virtualization in Windows 10

Tags: windows, virtualization

I am trying to install Docker. It is installed succesfully however when i run it, it asks for enabling hardware virtualization in bios. When i go into bios, i do not find any such option to enable it. Can anyone help me. Best

Comment: Have you installed virutal machine? Maybe you should add some context to address your problem more specific.

Comment: duplicate of [Cannot start docker after installation on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36885985/995714)